# How do I submit data populated from typeahead bloodhound auto complete

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js, bloodhound

How do I get typeahead to submit data.

Here is the relevant code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6W3Qu/2/.

A copy of the code:

```
var numbers = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: [
{ num: 'one' },
{ num: 'two' },
{ num: 'three' },
{ num: 'four' },
{ num: 'five' },
{ num: 'six' },
{ num: 'seven' },
{ num: 'eight' },
{ num: 'nine' },
{ num: 'ten' }
]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
numbers.initialize();

// instantiate the typeahead UI
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
displayKey: 'num',
source: numbers.ttAdapter(),
updater: function(item) {
    alert(item);
}
});
```

It doesn't seem to enter the updater function

Comment: never mind, figured it out

Comment: Can you please mention how?

Comment: @AnilKumarMuppalla As Ben smith pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeahead.js doesn't have an "updater" option.

Instead you can write an event handler which will use typeahead's selected event (i.e. typeahead:selected) e.g.

```
var numSelectedHandler = function (eventObject, suggestionObject, suggestionDataset) {
    alert(suggestionObject.num);
};

typeahead.on('typeahead:selected', numSelectedHandler);
```

A working example can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/TXQdy/